# Changing Input.GetMouseButtonDown to use new Input System Package

Tags: unity, c#, input

I want to develop a new football game. I placed a cube called "BallTrigger" in the player's foot area. In this way, I wrote code so that the player can shoot the ball. But when the player hits the ball, he doesn't shoot. It gives the following error;

> InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the
> UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling
> to Input System package in Player Settings.
> Karakter.Update () (at
> Assets/Codes/Karakter.cs:22)

How do I fix this error?

Karakter.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Karakter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool ball;
    public GameObject ballobj;

    public float sut1, sut2;

    void Update()
    {
        if (ball) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                ballobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity =
                    transform.TransformDirection(
                        new Vector3(0, 0, Random.Range(sut1,sut2)
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BallTrigger.cs;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider nesne){
         if (nesne.gameObject.tag == "Ball") {
            transform.root.gameObject.GetComponent<Karakter> ().ball = true;
         }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider nesne){
         if (nesne.gameObject.tag == "Ball") {
            transform.root.gameObject.GetComponent<Karakter> ().ball = false;
         }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider nesne){
         if (nesne.gameObject.tag == "Ball") {
            transform.root.gameObject.GetComponent<Karakter> ().ball = true;
         }       
    }
}
```

[image: Unity editor screenshot showing error]

Comment: It looks like you may have created a second account, different from the one you originally used to post the question. This will make it harder to make edits, reply to answers, or accept the answer that works for you. To solve this, please [follow these instructions to merge your accounts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and regain full control of your question.

Comment: Have you tried using the Unity tutorial for it and are stuck on one point? https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html